# Azure Data Lake Store - File permission update

Tags: azure-cli

How do I update the permissions for a file?  I want to make it read-only.

Please help!

Comment: Have you made some attempt? Have you applied some suggets from some website/blog? If yes, can you notify the results of your attempts?

Comment: Where is your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

az dls fs access set-permission --account [your account] --path [your file path] --permission [permission you want]